# How to split two columns array into rows in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

When running this query:

```
SELECT id,col1,col2
  FROM  app_data.content_cards
```

I get a table like this:

```
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
| id | col1                          | col2   |
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
| 90 | {'one', 'two', 'three'}       | {1,2,3}|
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
| 91 | {'abc', 'def'}                | {1,2}  |
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
| 92 | {'asdf}                       | {1}    |
+----+-------------------------------+--------+
```

What I want to do now is get this same information but with the arrays splitted into rows so I get a result like this:

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id | col1                | col2  |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 90 | one                 | 1     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 90 | two                 | 2     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 90 | three               | 3     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 91 | abc                 | 1     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 91 | def                 | 2     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
| 92 | asdf                | 1     |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

As you can see I don't want to get rows with null value in "col1" and "col2".

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming col1 and col2 got the same number of elements , you can make a view with the UNNEST function to split it and then query it.

```
WITH unnested_col1 AS (
  SELECT id, unnest(col1) as col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY unnest(col1)) as row_num
  FROM app_data.content_cards
), unnested_col2 AS (
  SELECT id, unnest(col2) as col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY unnest(col2)) as row_num
  FROM app_data.content_cards
)
SELECT unnested_col1.id, unnested_col1.col1, unnested_col2.col2
FROM unnested_col1
JOIN unnested_col2 ON unnested_col1.id = unnested_col2.id AND unnested_col1.row_num = unnested_col2.row_num
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `UNNEST` on both columns:

```
SELECT id,
UNNEST(col1) AS col1,
UNNEST(col2) AS col2
FROM content_cards
ORDER BY id;
```

See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html)

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QG6lt8g1)

Answer (score 2):

To make sure that matching array entries wind up on the same row, pass both arrays to a single unnest() call:

```
SELECT c.id, u.*
FROM content_cards c
    cross join unnest(col1, col2) as u(col1, col2)
ORDER BY id;
```

This guarantees that elements from matching array positions wind up in the same row even if one array has a different number of elements (the missing ones will be filled with `null` values).

If it's possible that some arrays have not elements at all but you still want to see the `id` of the base table, use an outer join:

```
FROM content_cards c
   left join unnest(col1, col2) as u(col1, col2) on true
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/esXxt0ie)